# SQL Except Select with different number of columns in two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two SQL Tables, which both have three columns

Normal

```
val_one, val_two, bool_val
1, 2, False
3, 4, False
```

Temp

```
val_one, val_two, bool_val
1, 2, True
```

I have a SQL statement that can select all of the rows from one that don't exist in the other table.

```
"SELECT val_one, val_two, bool_val FROM temp EXCEPT SELECT val_one, val_two, bool_val FROM normal;"
```

However, this has the problem that it also returns rows with different bool values, which is not what I want. So if I query, I only want to get back rows with different (val_one, val_two) values

In this example, my query would ideally return only

```
3, 4, False
```

How can I modify the current statement to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use not exists as below

```
SELECT val_one, val_two, bool_val FROM normal n
where not exists 
     (
          SELECT 1 FROM temp t  where t.val_one=n.val_one and t.val_two=n.val_two
      )
```

DB-Fiddle

```
 create table normal(val_one int, val_two int, bool_val varchar(10));
 insert into normal values(1, 2, False);
 insert into normal values(3, 4, False);

 create table temp(val_one int, val_two int, bool_val varchar(10));
 insert into temp values(1, 2, True);
```

Query:

```
 SELECT val_one, val_two, bool_val FROM normal n
 where not exists 
      (
           SELECT 1 FROM temp t  where t.val_one=n.val_one and t.val_two=n.val_two
       )
```

Output:

| val_one | val_two | bool_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | false |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=76b937e6481450da05fad05c228846cf)*

Comment: Thank you this worked well for me. I had to change the order of normal and temp to fit my use case, but I understood the example. :)

Comment: @SeanPayne you are most welcome. It's good to know that it helped. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the two values `val_one, val_two` with the `EXCEPT` statement and then join it to the `normal` table and return the values equal to `val_one, val_two`.

```
SELECT T2.val_one, T2.val_two, T2.bool_val FROM
(SELECT val_one, val_two FROM normal EXCEPT SELECT val_one, val_two FROM temp) T1
JOIN normal T2 ON T1.val_one = T2.val_one AND T1.val_two = T2.val_two
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided nulls are not considered "equal" one way is

```
SELECT val_one, val_two, bool_val 
FROM temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
              SELECT 1
              FROM normal n
              WHERE n.val_one = t.val_one AND t.val_two = n.val_two);
```